# How do I integrate my website with AICC for LMS

Tags: scorm

I want my website to be published as content in an LMS, one of the experts suggested me to use either SCORM and AICC. They suggested that we should make a wrapper around our website and then publish it on the LMS. Now I tried to search and read about SCROM and AICC but was not able to get any idea or how the wrapper has to be built.If someone can guide me with a blog or make steps of how should we achieve this.

Comment: Do you just want your site to be used as a 'asset' meaning no tracking or is your intent to add SCORM (scoring, bookmarking, progress, status etc ...) ?

Comment: We want the ability to interact with the LMS so yes as a SCORM

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you have a few e-Learning Content Libraries out around the internet in a free and paid capacity.  The primary job is to locate the LMS Runtime API.  Your implementation is possible, but it would take some careful packaging and some custom work to get it done.

Every e-learning developer has to commonly build a Shareable Content Object player.  This can be done using a IFRAME that loads pages.  This allows the main page the LMS launches to load once, and unload once.  Another route modern content takes, is to use AJAX to load in snippets of HTML and have a similar paging feel without the overhead of the IFRAME.

The next hurdle is trying to mitigate the cross-domain policy...

As you mentioned you could go AICC mainly because its cross-domain enabled.  AICC is a bit more limited in what you can record though.  Keep in mind this standard predates XML.  So we are in the text with delimiters category of configuration.

SCORM is going to have a cross-domain security (sandbox) error associated with the JavaScript on your website trying to talk to the LMS.  There is away around this, by possibly including your base index.html page which can use your JavaScript, CSS, Images on your website.  But, if your website changes pages, we are back to my above comment.  We need to wrap this in a IFRAME.

In the IFRAME scenario, you'd have to put your e-learning standard library there. And your sub pages in the IFRAME could talk to the parent.  This ensures your main page and all sub pages have a line of sight to parent of the frame and can make calls if its present.

All of this really depends on how you built your website.  We run content off media servers similarly, and have these same hurdles, but the content is meant to be activities, games, and tests/quizzes.  If you adjust your website to try and communicate this way you'll have to pad it for working with and without a LMS and any runtime data.

You can still launch a website as a asset though.  Not graded as a option.  Some commonly do this as part of a lesson where the student can read something, then take a test on it in a subsequent assignment.

Good Luck,
Mark